# 404 response when requesting current user via post request(Oauth2)

Tags: python, coinbase-api

I'm trying to find out more info about the user and have looked at the docs which has helped some but i'm stuck since i keep getting back a 404 response when i request my the data. I've tried flipping the headers2 var with the data1 var as well but the same response.https://docs.cloud.coinbase.com/sign-in-with-coinbase/docs/api-users (here's the documentation i'm using)

```
def info(token):
    data1 = {'Authorization':token}
    headers1 = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',"Authorization": "Bearer"}
    r = requests.post("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/user/", data=data1, headers=headers1)
    print(r)
```

Answer (score -1):

The request should be a **get** and not a **post**. The token goes in the **Authorization** header using the format **Bearer [token]**

```
 def info(token):
    headers1 = {
        "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}
    r = requests.get("https://api.coinbase.com/v2/user/", headers=headers1)
    print(r)
```